Is the phrase "piqued my attention" correct?
I've seen people saying "piqued my interest is correct, but I'm not too sure about"piqued my attention."
Example:
The name she mentioned piqued my interest
The name she mentioned piqued my attention
Which one is okay?
Or is it just the same thing?

Please look up words before posting.

A useful tool for finding out whether a phrase is commonly used is Google Books Ngram Viewer, which basically searches all of Google Books, which is a bit more reliable place to look for meaningful usages than the internet at large. This result shows that, no, there are hardly any uses of "pique [someone's] attention," compared to "pique [someone's] interest." Some other verbs that are often used in the same way with "attention" are "attract [someone's] attention" or "catch [someone's] attention."
Another noun that's often used with "pique" is curiosity.
This is partly because of the meaning and etymology of "pique." It comes from a French word for a pricking, stinging sensation, and in this usage has turned into something like "stimulate." "Interest" and "curiosity" are moods that someone can feel,  while "attention" is more just something they do.

NGrams is certainly a useful tool, but it's worth thinking about which form of a word (verb tense, noun plurality,...) to search for. Not hat the overall shape of the chart would be much different, but past tense is usually more common than present tense / infinitive for verbs..

@FumbleFingers Agreed, it should come with a warning that it can be hard to formulate the right query, and easy to misinterpret the results.

"easy to misinterpret the results". How true! Over the years I've had it pointed out to me dozens of times that I'm misinterpreting an NGram chart (invariably, in a way that supports whatever I happen to think! :)

Something gets your attention, but attention cannot be aroused or excited ("piqued") as  curiosity or interest can be.  But your curiosity or interest cannot be piqued by something until it has your attention.
Typically something catches, grabs, gets, holds your attention.
https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=piqued+my+attention%2Cpiqued+my+interest%2Cpiqued+my+curiosity&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3
